# select a file using lighttpn and start a shell script with the selected file as input

Tags: php, html, bash, shell

How can I select a file on my local machine using an html file on my lighttpn webserver and start a shell script with the selected file as input? Lets say i have a script for unpacking an archive with unrar. First I visit the website on my webserver and choose the file. The "unpacking-script" should be started with the path to the file as input. Lets say the output is always the same. This is a very simple html file with file selection. But I don't know how to start the script with the file as input.

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to use some javascript

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? I never used Java script before. I read that i need a PHP file that sends the selected file to the script. But the example i found is to Start a script using a button in a HTML site.